# Why would sending mail through smtp.gmail.com (using gmail - for business - standard edition) cause it to get delivered multiple times?

Tags: email, gmail

**Important Update - This is a Current Google Problem - see my answer**

---

We have recently migrated from an inhouse exchange server to gmail (using google apps for business).  The migration has been far from flawless and I'm about to lose my mind!  Almost all problems have been corrected and sorted out except for this one which is really confusing.

When our users who are using outlook exclusively (POP3 access to their gmail account) sends an email it will be delivered multiple times.

It appears that the delivery of the additional emails (which are duplicates of the original) hit the recipients inbox again hours after the original was sent.

It is worth noting that at the times the additional emails are delivered outlook has been closed and the machines logged off (and have been for hours).

It's also worth noting that one of our clients mentioned that when they open the email (i.e. double click it in outlook) the received time changes to the time the original email was sent.

Any ideas? (I'm waiting to receive the email headers from one of the 'message chains').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it's a problem at google's end... I don't know if I feel that's a good or a bad thing. :|

Have to wait until its fixed:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=4ec0aff919d4a7c3&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a screenshot, you should ask those clients to provide you with the headers of all received copies of the same mail.  The "Received" headers could give an indication about where things go wrong.

Comment: I've now requested these... as soon as I have them I will post them here.  Do you have any initial ideas based on the information I have submitted already?  I'm keen to get a few ideas, of what it could be, so that I can research the heck out of it - but I'm really confused by this one.

Comment: I suspected what curiouscoder seems to confirm: there are issues with Google's mail infrastructure.